# Carrierwave - Multiple images upload too slow when adding or removing images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, image-uploading

I'm following this article in CarrierWave Wiki https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Add-more-files-and-remove-single-file-when-using-default-multiple-file-uploads-feature to implement adding more images and removing images for a model in my system using CarrierWave Multiple Uploads feature.

The main code in that article is

```ruby
def add_more_images(new_images)
  images = @gallery.images 
  images += new_images
  @gallery.images = images
end

def remove_image_at_index(index)
  remain_images = @gallery.images # copy the array
  deleted_image = remain_images.delete_at(index) # delete the target image
  deleted_image.try(:remove!) # delete image from S3
  @gallery.images = remain_images # re-assign back
end
```

It works. **However, it is too slooooow.** I have looked at the log and the overall processing time is as follow:

1. Upload 1 image: it takes 5000ms for example
2. Add 1 more image: it takes 8500ms (2 images)
3. Add 1 more image: it takes 12000ms (3 images)
4. Remove 1 image: it takes 8400ms (back to 2 images)

I have tested the sample app of this solution written by the author on my local machine and it was very slow too.

**It seems like CarrierWave reuploads and re-processes all images even we only add or remove 1 image. I think because we are re-assigning back new array of images to @gallery so that it treats old images as new ones.**

Also there is a related issue here https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1704#issuecomment-259106600

Does anyone have any better solution for adding and removing images using CarrierWave multiple upload feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `model.images = remain_images`, carrierwave will upload all images. So the more images you stored in a column, the longer it will take.
See: [mount.rb#L300](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/87c37b706c560de6d01816f9ebaa15ce1c51ed58/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L300), [mounter.rb#L40](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/97c028cc0ee8e6e84a3b60ae60fd4f59703f8a40/lib/carrierwave/mounter.rb#L40)

I had this problem before, the following is my code:

```
new_images = self.logo_images.clone
4.times do |t|
  next if !(image = params[:"logo_image#{t + 1}"])
  new_images[t] = image
  changed = true
end
self.logo_images = new_images if changed
...
self.save if changed
```

And this is the hack...

(works fine with `carrierwave 1.0.0` and `carrierwave-aws 1.1.0`)

```
mounter = self.send(:_mounter, :logo_images)
4.times do |t|
  next if !(image = params[:"logo_image#{t + 1}"])
  uploader = mounter.blank_uploader
  uploader.cache!(image)
  mounter.uploaders[t] = uploader
  changed = true
end
mounter.uploaders.each{|s| s.send(:original_filename=, s.file.filename) if !s.filename} if changed 
...
self.save if changed
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code. It looks like for each  `logo_image[x]` param provided, it will cache and add the image to a new blank_uploader, then it iterates all the new uploaders and assigns `original_filename`. So let's we had 4 images before, and now the user action only sends 3 in params (to represent a deleted image)... how does this prevent the reupload of original 3 images?

Comment: The code can only add or replace images. Let `logo_images` be `[nil, image1, image2]` and user upload a new image `params[:logo_image3]`. If you use `add_more_images([params[:logo_image3]])`, carrierwave will upload `image1`, `image2`, and `params[:logo_image3]`. But if you use my code, it will only upload `params[:logo_image3]`.

Comment: I am not sure how to delete image. You could try `mounter.uploaders[t]&.remove!` to remove image. `mounter.uploaders.delete_at(t)` to remove uploader. Then iterates all the uploaders and assigns original_filename.